# In React compare two array of object then check checkbox accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React I'm creating a multiple choice questionnaire. Checkboxes are generated with the possible answers. When the user ticks the answers and reloads the page, the chosen answers' checkboxes do not retained their checked state.

The questions and answers are fetched from database as an array of objects on 1st load. The user can tick multiple checkboxes for a question. A 2nd array is created that includes all the multiple answers that user has chosen and sent to database has objects. On reload, this 2nd array is added to the state of the component as well as the 1st array.

#### Component

```js
const Checkbox = ({ id, name, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="checkbox-group">
      {options.map((option, index) => {
        <div key={index}>
          <label htmlFor={id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={name}
              id={id}
              value={option}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
            {option}
          </label>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      questionnaire: [],
      answeredQuestions: [],
      formData: {},
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // it doesn't matter how I fetch the data, could have been axios, etc...
    let questionnaire = await fetch(questionnaireUrl);
    let answeredQuestions = await fetch(answeredQuestionsUrl);

    this.setState({ questionnaire, answeredQuestions });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="questionnaire-panel">

        <h1>Quiz</h1>

        {this.state.questionnaire.map((question, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <Checkbox
                options={questions.answers}
                checked={// this where I'm stuck on what to do}
                name="the-quiz"
                id={`the-quiz_num_${index + 1}`}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    let value = target.value;
    let name = target.name;

    let chosenAnwersArray = [];

    let chosenAnswer = {
      answer: value,
      checked: true,
    };

    if (this.state.questionnaire.includes(chosenAnswer)) {
      newChosenAnwersArray = this.state.questionnaire.filter(q => {
        return q.answer !== chosenAnswer.answer;
      });
    } else {
      newChosenAnwersArray = [...newChosenAnwersArray, chosenAnswer];
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      formData: {
        [name]: value,
      },
      answeredQuestions: newChosenAnwersArray 
    }));
  }
}
```

I want to compare these 2 arrays that are in the `this.state`, that if the answers in the array2 are in array1 then check the corresponding checkboxes. Is there is a better way, please teach me!